# Как горизонтально проскроллить блок до левой части экрана?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Необходимо, чтобы при клике на блок он раскрывался и становился прижатым к левой части экрана (если это возможно) либо к правой.
 Ниже прикрепил `Pen` примера, подскажите пожалуйста как проскроллить `.row` до нужной позиции исходя из расположения `.main-block`

https://codepen.io/MB116/pen/ZjNLpp

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/MB116/pen/ZjNLpp

Задал всем main-block их номер в порядке, у активного же (.active) задается order: 0

```
.main-block-1 {
   background-color: #000;
   order: 0;
}

.main-block-2 {
   background-color: #f00;
   order: 1;
}

.main-block-3 {
   background-color: #0f0;
   order: 2;
}

.main-block-4 {
   background-color: #00f;
   order: 3;
}
```